# Getting ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION in django

Tags: python, django

I am getting ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION in Chrome browser with the following given code below in django.

```
redirect_path = 'some-url'
response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_path)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file-from-+324#10,+4324.mp3'
return response
```

Things are working find in other browser.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong on this.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to set the `Content-Disposition` header for a redirect response. A redirect response is telling the browser to follow the redirect, it doesn't contain the file you are redirecting to.

Comment: @Alasdair, that was present in our legacy code since always, things are working fine in other browser except chrome.

Comment: Other browsers might not give any error, but I'm still not convinced that setting the header on a response will have any effect. I tested with Safari, which follows the redirect and appears to ignore the `Content-Disposition` header.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you have a comma in the filename. The filename in the header should be quoted. I tested that the following view works in Chrome.

```
def my_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse('hello')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filename,with,commas.txt"'
    return response
```

See [this discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/H_DneQinvT0/discussion) on the Chrome help forum for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Further to the answer from @Alasdair to remove the commas from the filename, if it is generated dynamically, you can call `.replace()` when constructing the filename in the `response` object.  Then the below:

```
redirect_path = 'some-url'
response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_path)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file-from-+324#10,+4324.mp3'
return response
```

becomes

```
redirect_path = 'some-url'
filename_to_return = "file-from-+324#10,+4324.mp3".replace(',', '_')
response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_path)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename_to_return
return response
```

You just have to replace the filename string with the dynamic variable that gets passed into the function.